# Can I set the esapi org.owasp.esapi.SecurityConfiguration proeprty in a properties file?

Tags: spring, jboss, esapi

I'm using JBoss 7.1.3, Spring 3.1.4.RELEASE, Java 6, esapi 2.0.1, and building a web (WAR) application.  I would like to set the property "org.owasp.esapi.SecurityConfiguration" to "org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultSecurityConfiguration" but I would like to do it somewhere in my WAR file.  Is there anywhere within my WAR file that I can define my property like this?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Do you have some code/configuration with your attempts?

Comment: Some more context would be useful.  I've installed ESAPI in at least 3 applications now, and I don't recall ever needing to set that property.  Typically you just need to handle `esapi.properites` and `validation.properties` and point `log4j.properties` to esapi's log4jFactory, and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I also don't fully understand your question either. This is already the default behavior so it should not be necessary to change this.

org.owasp.esapi.SecurityConfiguration is an *interface*; org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultSecurityConfiguration is the default (and only) concrete ESAPI class that implements that interface. So that is *already* the default of what ESAPI is already using.

Now there is a way to change that default concrete class that implements the SecurityConfiguration interface. (Is that what you meant?) First you would have to implement your own class which implements the SecurityConfiguration interface to replace DefaultSecurityConfiguration. Then you would have to set the System property "org.owasp.esapi.SecurityConfiguration" to your fully qualified class name. E.g., you could do that by setting it on the java command line: -Dorg.owasp.esapi.SecurityConfiguration=com.mycompany.MyESAPISecurityConfigurator.
There are other ways to change it (see the Javadoc for the ESAPI class for details), but they might occur "too late" depending on what you are trying to do and your reasons for wishing to replace DefaultSecurityConfiguration (if that is indeed really what you intended to do).

-kevin

Comment: Hi, Ok, let's say I was implementing my own class, how would I set the configuration in my WAR file (like my question states)?  I understand System.setProperty is a method, but I would prefer to do this via some other configuration (like setting a property in a properties file or something)